# Ошибка при MySQL-запросе: "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource"

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Не могу понять, в чём ошибка:

```
$line[2] = 13;
$query = "SELECT * FROM Klient WHERE id = ".$line[2]."";
$klient_v_for = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
$klent_v_i = mysql_fetch_array($klient_v_for, MYSQL_BOTH);
```

Массив `$klent_v_i` не формируется.

Если вывести ошибку:

```
mysql_error($query = "SELECT * FROM Klient WHERE id = ".$line[2]."");
```

Выдает:

> `Warning: mysql_error(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in site.ru/script.php on line 99`

При этом если я вместо `$line[2]` ставлю просто число 13, то все работает как надо.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Klient WHERE id = 13";
$klient_v_for = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
$klent_v_i = mysql_fetch_array($klient_v_for, MYSQL_BOTH);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Comment: id строкового типа?

Comment: id строкового типа?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/42808)

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/42808)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/42808)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/42808)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался вроде:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Klient WHERE id = '$line[2]'";
```

Comment: Вы верно разобрались;)